# Make org-agenda show only first occurrence of recurring task?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In Org-Mode, I have a few mundane re-occuring tasks.

When a task is set to re-occur, it shows up on every day it reccours. E.g a daily task:

```
* TODO Bugzilla Triage 
 SCHEDULED <[today] ++1d>

Week-agenda (W09):
Monday     23 February 2015 W09
  leo:        Scheduled:  TODO Bugzilla Triage                      :RECURRING::
  leo:        Deadline:   TODO Weekly report                        :RECURRING::
Tuesday    24 February 2015
  leo:        Scheduled:  TODO Bugzilla Triage                      :RECURRING::
Wednesday  25 February 2015
  leo:        Scheduled:  TODO Bugzilla Triage                      :RECURRING::
Thursday   26 February 2015
  leo:        Scheduled:  TODO Bugzilla Triage                      :RECURRING::
Friday     27 February 2015
  leo:        Scheduled:  TODO Bugzilla Triage                      :RECURRING::
Saturday   28 February 2015
Sunday      1 March 2015
```

I don't really want them to take up all the Agenda space, I just want to see the first occurrence, (i.e only monday's occurance, but not all the other occurrences). Is it possible to configure emacs to show only the first occurance? (i.e monday in this case)

Comment: You can set `org habits` to only show the next occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mankoff's solution of using Habits worked.

```
I enabled habits in org mode via the org-modules variable.
I enabled state logging (see below for details)
I then created a task with style set to habits.
Now when I complete the task, it is not seen until the day it is scheduled again.
```

example of a task:

```
** TODO [#C] Mail / BZ Triage                                        :RECURRING:
SCHEDULED: <2015-02-13 Fri .+1d>
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2015-02-12 Thu 11:13]
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2015-02-12 Thu 11:13]
:STYLE:    habit
:END:
```

Details: http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution with an example?

Comment: I edited my question and added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

In org-mode 9.1 the line:

```
(setq org-agenda-show-future-repeats 'next)
```

Makes habits only show up the next time they are scheduled.